# Wait for `insertAdjacentElement` to update DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-node

I am practicing html/vanilla JS by building a tic tac toe app. I add an event listener to the board square `<div>`s, and create elements with X and O and insert them into the DOM, then call a function to check if there is a winner. The `checkIfPlayerWins()` function does some checking and then calls and `alert` if the players wins or there is a draw.

The problem I am running into is that if a player wins, the alert is being called before the X or O is inserted into the DOM which just looks funny. I would like to not use a `setTimeout` as that just seems a bit hacky. I tried `async`/`await` and also creating a `new Promise` from it but can't seem to get it to work.

Okay here is some code and relevant links:
[insertAdjacentElement MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)
My [github/ code repo](https://github.com/mmudge/tic-tac-toe)

```
  setEventListeners() {
    const board = document.querySelector('.board')
    const squares = board.children

    for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      squares[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const squareEl = event.target
        if (!squareEl.firstChild) {
          this.makeMove(squareEl)
        } else {
          alert('That square is already taken!')
        }
      })
    }
  }

  makeMove(eventTarget) {
    let playerMarker = ''
    if (this.playerOneTurn) {
      playerMarker = 'X'
    } else {
      playerMarker = 'O'
    }

    eventTarget.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', createElementFromHTML(`<div>${playerMarker}</div>`))

    this.updateGameState(eventTarget.className, playerMarker)

    this.playerOneTurn = !this.playerOneTurn
    this.updatePlayerTurnText()
  }

export function createElementFromHTML(htmlString) {
  const template = document.createElement('template')
  template.innerHTML = htmlString.trim()
  return template.content.firstChild
}

  updateGameState(squareName, playerMarker) {
    this.gameState[squareName] = playerMarker
    this.checkIfPlayerWins()
  }

  checkIfPlayerWins() {
    // TODO make this smarter
    const winningIndexes = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6],
    ]

    let winner = null

    winningIndexes.forEach((combos) => {
      if (combos.every((combo) => this.gameState[`square-${combo + 1}`] === 'X')) {
        winner = this.playerOne
      } else if (combos.every((combo) => this.gameState[`square-${combo + 1}`] === 'O')) {
        winner = this.playerTwo
      }
    })

    if (Object.values(this.gameState).every((square) => square != '')) {
      alert('Game is a draw!')
    } else if (winner) {
      alert(`${winner} wins!!`)
    }
  }
```

These are all the relevant functions, and if you see in the `makeMove()` function, I call `eventTarget.insertAdjacentElement`, but then I call `updatePlayerTurn()` which calls `checkIfPlayerWins()` which calls the `alert()`. This `alert()` in the `checkIfPlayerWins()` function is executing before the `insertAdjacentElement` element gets inserted into the DOM. Can anyone help me figure out how I can wait for the DOM changes to happen before the `alert()` gets called? Thanks!

Comment: `alert` blocks the UI from updating. You can use `requestAnimationFrame` if `setTimeout(fn, 0)` seems too "hacky".

Comment: shouldn't the DOM have already updated though? `alert` stops previous code? Any relevant links for me to learn more about this?

Comment: There are a number of links in the answers to the question linked in my second comment. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/ comes right from a browser vendor...

Comment: Great links, thanks! So all the JS will run before a new paint of the DOM, so my code is hanging on the `alert` before the element is rendered to the DOM and so making the alerts asynchronous makes the code not hang on it. Cool, okay so I guess using `setTimeout` on the alert isn't as hacky as I previously thought. Thanks!